# Is "with" Within Elixir a New Scope?

Tags: elixir

I'm guessing that within a `with` in Elixir, any variables in the block are local to the block.  I made this code to test my assumption:

```
defmodule T do
  def test do
    r1 = nil
    r2 = nil

    with(
      r1 <- Enum.find([9], &(&1 >= 9)),
      r2 <- Enum.find([2], &(&1 <= 2))
    ) do
    end

    IO.write("r1 is nil is #{is_nil(r1)}, r2 is nil is #{is_nil(r2)}")
  end
end
```

And as expected, `r1` and `r2` are `nil`.

Is there any way to check the bound values outside of the scope of the `with` or is that just the way it works?  I am asking because I was running some `Enum.finds` against an Enumerable and it'd be nice to be able to distinguish which one failed outside of the with block.

Comment: I think you can make the `with` actually return the values of r1 and r2 ...

Comment: You're right but I didn't ask the right question. I need to revise.

Comment: Is your question about scope, about using `with`, or about finding elements in a list? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, accessing outer scoped variables should be avoided as much as possible because that makes the code hard to reuse.

For a quick workaround, you can wrap the expression inside `with` to distinguish which fails like:

```
defmodule T do
  def test do
    with(
      {:r1, r1} when not is_nil(r1) <- {:r1, Enum.find([9], &(&1 >= 9))},
      {:r2, r2} when not is_nil(r2) <- {:r2, Enum.find([2], &(&1 <= 2))}
    ) do
      {:ok, r1, r2}
    else
      {:r1, nil} ->
        {:error, :r1_is_nil}

      {:r2, nil} ->
        {:error, :r2_is_nil}
    end
  end
end

T.test()
#=> {:ok, 9, 2}
```

However, I will recommend a more reusable way of validation inside `with`:

```
defmodule T do
  def test do
    with {:ok, r1} <- validate([9], &(&1 >= 9), :r1_is_nil),
         {:ok, r2} <- validate([2], &(&1 <= 2), :r2_is_nil) do
      {:ok, r1, r2}
    end
  end

  defp validate(numbers, validator, error) do
    case Enum.find(numbers, validator) do
      nil -> {:error, error}
      x -> {:ok, x}
    end
  end
end

T.test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not just `with`, but all code blocks delimited with `do`/`end`. There is a little bit written about this in the [case, cond, and if guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#if-and-unless):

> This is also a good opportunity to talk about variable scoping in Elixir. If any variable is declared or changed inside if, case, and
> similar constructs, the declaration and change will only be visible
> inside the construct. For example:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> x = 1
> 1
> iex> if true do
> ...>   x = x + 1
> ...> end
> 2
> iex> x
> 1
> ```

---

If you want to find elements in a list that satisfy multiple predicates, you could do something like this using [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce_while/3). It returns two maps: one with the identified elements, and one with the unsatisfied predicates.

```elixir
defmodule T do
  def test do
    list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    predicates = %{
      r1: &(&1 >= 9),
      r2: &(&1 <= 2)
    }

    Enum.reduce_while(list, {%{}, predicates}, fn
      _r, {_found, predicates} when map_size(predicates) == 0 -> 
       {:halt, {found, predicates}}

      r, {found, predicates} ->
        case Enum.find(predicates, fn {_tag, p} -> p.(r) end) do
          nil -> {:cont, {found, predicates}}
          {tag, _p} -> {:cont, {Map.put(found, tag, r), Map.delete(predicates, tag)}}
        end
    end)
  end
end
```

Result:

```elixir
iex(1)> T.test
{%{r2: 1}, %{r1: #Function<0.13302157/1 in T.test/0>}}
```